# guard-annotate gem is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guard

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'annotate'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-annotate'
```

**Guardfile**

```
guard 'annotate', :run_at_start => false do
  watch( 'db/schema.rb' )

  # Uncomment the following line if you also want to run annotate anytime
  # a model file changes
  watch( 'app/models/*.rb' )

  # Uncomment the following line if you are running routes annotation
  # with the ":routes => true" option
  watch( 'config/routes.rb' )
end
```

When I run "annotate"(without guard) it is working well. When I run guard I find the guard-annotate is not working.

Here is the trace

$ **bundle exec guard**

```
09:33:56 - INFO - Guard is using NotifySend to send notifications.
09:33:56 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
09:33:56 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/user/work/projects/a/alumni-not'
[1] guard(main)> 
09:34:56 - INFO - Run all
[2] guard(main)> 
09:34:56 - INFO - Run all
[3] guard(main)>
```

debug trace

**$ bundle exec guard --plugin annotate -d**

```
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
16:48:13 - INFO - Guard is using Libnotify to send notifications.
16:48:13 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Annotate
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::Annotate
16:48:13 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/user/work/projects/a/alumni-not'
16:48:13 - DEBUG - Start interactor
[1] Annotate guard(main)> 
16:48:23 - INFO - Run all
16:48:23 - DEBUG - Hook :run_all_begin executed for Guard::Annotate
16:48:23 - DEBUG - Hook :run_all_end executed for Guard::Annotate
```

I can't find any results here but I can find some processes going around.How can I solve this problem?? Where should I see annotated results?

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile

gem "rails", "3.1.0"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"

group :development do
  gem "annotate", "2.5.0"
end

command line:

$ gem install annotate
Successfully installed annotate-2.5.0
1 gem installed

Comment: guard-annotate has a direct dependency in the annotate gem, see https://rubygems.org/gems/guard-annotate

Answer (score 0):

Guard annotate [does not implement the `run_all` plugin API](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/guard-annotate/blob/master/lib/guard/annotate.rb#L38), so run all has no effect for the annotate Guard.

I don't know the annotate gem, but from a quick look it seems that it anyway does annotate always every model and does not have a selective regeneration, so you simply can trigger a single file change like

```
[1] guard(main)> c db/schema.rb
```

This should run the annotations.

Another option is to send a pull request to implement the `run_all` method like:

```
def run_all
  run_annotate
end
```

This allows you to write `annotate` into the Guard command prompt to run the annotations.

Answer (score -1):

Use specific version of `gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"` as later version of gem has deleted the ui part.

or

you can use gem `"jquery-ui-rails"` for `jquery-ui` . For more information please visit the git repository

To require all jQuery UI modules, add the following to your application.js:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Also add the jQuery UI CSS to your application.css:

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 */
```

Hope this could help you

Answer (score -2):

Are you running this from the command prompt? If so try bundle exec annotate User to use your bundled gems rather than the system gems.

And is the gem called 'annotate' or 'annotate-models'?

Comment: Hey, guard-annotate should do that on your behalf, only if the `db/schema.rb` file gets changes. However your comment about running `bundle exec annotate` manually did work for me. Though it doesn't answer why guard-annotate isn't running correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't it be annotate gem? Its github repo is called annotate_models.

annotate-models gem is different and hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: I believe guard-annotate brings in annotate as a dependancy.